# MSTest F# - running tests in parallel

Tags: f#, mstest

Following the guide mentionned here: [Using MSTest with F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103964/using-mstest-with-f) I managed to successfully run my unit tests.

I was wondering if anyone had tried and successfully managed to run tests in parallel?

[How to run unit tests (MSTest) in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917060/how-to-run-unit-tests-mstest-in-parallel)

Thanks!

edit:

So I ended up deleting all solution items, removing the C# test project cleaned solution.
Readded a new C# test project with Local.testsettings (I had Debug.testsettings and Release.testsettings - adding Local.testsettings manually hadn't fixed the problem). Fixed - running 5 tests in parallel.

Comment: Did you try the method detailed in the link you gave? `parallelTestCount`

Comment: Yes, considering I gave the link I did indeed try it. I'm starting to think my runner ignores my testsettings files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the composition of [Using MSTest with F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103964/using-mstest-with-f) and [How to run unit tests (MSTest) in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917060/how-to-run-unit-tests-mstest-in-parallel) allows to run up to 5 F#-written local unit tests in parallel with VS2010/mstest on a multi-core box. The screenshot below shows `TestMethod2()` and `TestMethod3()` are running in parallel, while `TestMethod4()` has already being passed, and `TestMethod1()` is still pending.

Environment is VS2010 Premium/no SP1 running on 16-core box under Win2008R2; `parallelTestCount` attribute of `<Execution>` element in `Local.testsettings` is set to `2`:

```
<Execution parallelTestCount="2">
```

Non-scaled version of the screenshot image can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iu73f.jpg)

[image: VS2010 with two F# unit tests running in parallel]

Good luck with "native" VS/mstest F# unit testing! :)

Comment: I'm actually glad to see it's working for you... I'll just keep trying thanks! As a side question, considering the ctrl+r,t shortcuts do not seem to work with F#, I assume you have no choice but to work with the Test List Editor/Test View window?

Comment: Is there any incentive not to install sp1?

Comment: @David re VS SP1: I just simply stated the characteristics of the involved environment, which is kinda "controlled", i.e. application of updates/service packs is decided by an external authority. They do not think it's time for VS SP1 yet :)

Comment: @David re shortcuts: `ctrl+r,t` works like a charm in my environment

Comment: It runs every single test in the solution no matter what. I would expect it to run all test in my test class or a specific unit test.